# Algorithm to Select Sequential Subarrays from an Array

Tags: algorithms, code-quality

I solved my problem by using simple nested loops and comparisons but I'm wondering if there is a well known Selection Algorithm to solve my problem.

Let's say I have an array such as

[1, 10, 250, 9, 8,8, 249, 249, 248, 247, 2, 4, 9, 10, 9, 7, 6]

I need to find subarrays

[6,7,8,9,10] [8,9,10] [247, 248, 249, 250]

Subarrays should be min. 3 length size.

I dont want a solution but a similar algorithm would help me refactor my code.

I'm currently doing this with nested loops and using buffer collections.

Comment: If the original array contained an 11, how should the subarrays be listed?

Comment: [6,7,8,9,10,11] [8,9,10] [247, 248, 249, 250]

Comment: there is no order in subarrays. All items can only be used one time in subarrays

Comment: The necessary determination was if `[6,7,8,9,10,11] [8,9,10]` was the only answer or if `[6,7,8,9,10] [8,9,10,11]` is a valid answer.

Comment: they are both valid answers as long as 11 is used once

Comment: What are the rules for selecting the subarrays? Why is [8,9,10] a valid answer but not [7,8,9,10] or [248,249,250]?

Comment: valid answer was not [8,9,10], it was [[6,7,8,9,10] [8,9,10] [247, 248, 249, 250]] in the sample.(all possible subarrays)

Comment: @AlanT there were multiple `8` `9` `10` so they were used in two different subarray